# DOMNodeList returns DOMNode or DOMElement?

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

I'm missing something here...

I have this command:

> $xpath->query('//input')->item(0)

The php.net documentation says that DOMNodeList:item should return a DOMNode  http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php, but if I var_dump the result of the above it says it return a DOMElement!

Is php.net wrong or it's me?

PS: I greatly prefer that it returns a DOMElement though, looks quite more logic!

Comment: [DOMElement extends DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)

Comment: The problem is that documentation says it return a DOMNode, while instead it return a DOMelement! my problem is not what does it return, but the documentation! If there was written that a DOMElement was returned i could have saved a lot of time!

Comment: It does return a `DOMNode`... if you have a `DOMElement` `$dom`, then `$dom instanceof DOMNode` equals to `true`

Comment: This is tautology... the role for a documentation is to be as precise as possible, even more being the official docs. In this case there's one possible conclusion: the docs are wrong.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. If something is said to return a `Vehicle` and returns a `Car` instead, then it's wrong to say that car is not a vehicle. Given of course that `Car` extends `Vehicle`.

Comment: -_- then the docs are useless. People cannot go around guessing which subclass of a class is returned. Publishing a bug report on php.net...

Comment: They are not that useless, even if I was completely oblivious to different node types, I could still treat any node type as a node as is promised in the docs. If you publish a bug report though, can you give me the link :P

Comment: I found similar bug reports. The answer is that domnodelist->item() returns many kind of objects, all subclasses of DOMNode, but not just DOMElements. Well, a solution for the docs could be to write that it returns a DOMNode or one of is subclasses, even better specify which subclasses. The misunderstatement derived by me thinking that it returns only DOMElement, not other kind of objects.

Comment: @Bakaburg: I have to disagree, not to derride you, but you and anyone else who brings this up is just mistaken. It returns and interface of `DOMNode` that is the **"contract"** of the API. Anything that is an instance of `DOMNode` is still a `DOMNode` even if its a descendent class. This is typical for pretty much any API documentation.

Comment: I don't agree, there should a way to warn developers that the returned value is one of the subclasses of an class and not the parent class. Evenmore, from what I could see, DOMNodeList::item() will never return a simple DOMNode. And it's not true that all the documentations do this! In cocoa (mac os x framework) every object inherit from NSObject, but of course they use the exact subclass returned, not the parent eg. (NSInteger)integerValue() a function of the NSControl class. And if there are many possible returned object kinds: (id)cell(), where id is a generic object pointer. This is clear!

Comment: @Bakaburg imho the PHP documentation is clear. `DOMNodeList::item()` returns an object of class `DOMNode`. That is guaranteed. There is no guarantee which subclass of `DOMNode` will be returned. It could be `DOMElement` but also `DOMComment` or `DOMText` and the list can contain any combination in any order. If the behavior depends on which exact subclass is returned, you need to check first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Esailija  said in his comment `DOMElement` extends `DOMNode` so it is indeed returning a `DOMNode`or rather an object that shares that interface. That said you cannot depend on it being a `DOMElement` so if you use `DOMElement` specific functionality you need to test that it is a `DOMElement` and not some other form of `DOMNode`.